# Error deduplicate while running sbt/sbt assembly

Tags: sbt

I am getting the following error while executing the command sbt/sbt assembly :

```
[error] (spark-cassandra-connector-java/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty/bundles/netty-3.8.0.Final.jar:org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/Bootstrap.class
[error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/org.jboss.netty/netty/bundles/netty-3.2.2.Final.jar:org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/Bootstrap.class
```

Answer (score 2):

the dependencies you are using any of two dependency are dependent dependency of netty so just exclude netty from on of them like below

```
 exclude("org.jboss.netty", "netty")
```

add above line in front of dependency from which u want to exclude.